Error in if ((resCritical[ncB - min_nc + 1, 3] >= alphaBeale) && (!foundBeale))
I have one issue when I ran the function NbClust:
The link of data file:
original cmtscore file:
https://github.com/Lancelof2019/data_link/blob/check/combine_PAAD_score_profile_test01.csv
After scale:
https://github.com/Lancelof2019/data_link/blob/check/scalescores_PAAD.csv
The desired output should display a number.
Then I got the issue:

Error in if ((resCritical[ncB - min_nc + 1, 3] >= alphaBeale) && (!foundBeale))
{ :    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning messages: 1: In pf(beale, pp, df2) : NaNs produced 2: In pf(beale, pp, df2) : NaNs produced

code:
###############data analysis#################
##### Patient stratification
options(stringsAsFactors = F)

library(NbClust)

#####################################


cancer_type<-"PAAD"
print("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
#print(cancer_type)
#getAnywhere(NbClust)

setwd("/users/ondemand/testSpace/code_and_data21/code")
user_home<-"/users/ondemand/testSpace/code_and_data21/code/"
#print(cancer_type)
#samples <- readRDS(paste0("../data/tcga_data_processed/",cancer_type,"_samples.RData"))


#length(samples_f2)
cmtScores <- read.csv(paste0("../data/python_related/result/community/combine_",cancer_type,"_score_profile_test01.csv"), check.names = F, header = F)


#View(cmtScores)
print(any(is.na(cmtScores)))
#scalescores<-scale(cmtScores)* 1e6
write.csv(scalescores,paste0(user_home,"scalescores_",cancer_type,".csv"))
#View(scalescores)
print(any(is.na(scalescores)))
#str(cmtScores)
nc <- NbClust(scale(cmtScores), distance = "euclidean", min.nc = 2, max.nc = 20, method = "complete", index = "all")

But I have tried to use
print(any(is.na(cmtScores)))
scalescores<-scale(cmtScores)* 1e6

The output is false, there is no NaN.
However, the issue still exists.

You may get better, faster help if you edit this to be a minimal reproducible example. Most of this code and these libraries are not needed
